# "git rm --cached <filename>" also remove <file> in Working Copy

Tags: git

My *working directory* is:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA
$ ls
book.json  README.md  SUMMARY.md
```

Now i will add "README.md" to ".gitignore":

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA!
$ cat .gitignore
README.md
```

Then let's remove the file:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA!
$ git rm --cached README.md
rm 'README.md'
```

And 'add' staging area:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA!
$ git add . 

~/Desktop/git_que on brA!
$ git status
On branch brA
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    deleted:    README.md
```

Nice, let's 'commit':

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA!
$ git commit -m "ignore README.md"
[brA 5e80102] ignore README.md
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 29 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 README.md

~/Desktop/git_que on brA
$ git status
On branch brA
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Let's list files at directory:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA
$ ls
book.json  README.md  SUMMARY.md
```

So nice, as expected. Now, lets switch th branch to 'brB' and return to 'brA' again:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA
$ git checkout brB
Switched to branch 'brB'

~/Desktop/git_que on brB
$ git checkout brA
Switched to branch 'brA'
```

Again lets list files at directory:

```
~/Desktop/git_que on brA
$ ls
book.json  SUMMARY.md
```

So, i can't see my README.md file.

**Question-1:** Where is my  file, why i can't see it anymore?

**Question-2:** I want to ignore this file, but i want to continue work with it. I mean, *GIT* not track it, not share anywhere; but the file remain in my local working directory. How can i do this?

Comment: *cherry-pick* this commit to all of your branches.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle but i thought the '.gitignore' is **branch specified**.
The file may remain as tracked in another branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git rm --cached` did not remove the file.

`git checkout` *did* remove the file.

The reason is simple: the file is *not tracked* (and does not exist in) your new commit.  The file *is* tracked (because it *does* exist in the commit) when you check out your old commit.  So when you check out your old commit, the file is tracked, and then when you switch from that old commit to the new commit, Git sees that the tracked file is gone from the new commit, and removes it.

The root of the problem is that *is path P tracked?* is a property of the *index*, and `git checkout` fills the index from the commit.  So the "is tracked" property *changes*—at least potentially—with each change to "which commit is the checked-out commit".

Moving from a commit in which a file is tracked, to a commit that does not have the file, removes the file from the *work-tree* (and from the index—in fact, removing it from the index is *why* Git removes it from the work-tree).  Moving from a commit that does not have the file, to one that does, *adds* the file *to* the work-tree (and to the index—in fact, adding it to the index is *why* Git adds ti to the work-tree).

This is what makes having a file in some commits, and not in others, when you would like to have it in *no* commits but remain in the work-tree at all times, such a big problem.  There is no perfect solution to this.  You can to use a different *name* for the file, that occurs in no commits; or you can carefully avoid checking out any commit that *does* have the file, that causes the file to go into the index and thus be tracked.

Comment: I see, thanks for explanation. According to working principle you explained, you right; no solution simply.